# Cygwin make dependencies fail

Tags: makefile, dependencies, cygwin

I'm using Windows 7, and the command make dependencies fails in CYGWIN. 
'make' works and shows the complete list of available targets. make clean works without generating an error message. All the rest fails and the error is:

```
$ make dependencies
Installing depencies
make: Rscript : commande introuvable
../Makefile:39: recipe for target `dependencies' failed
make: *** [dependencies] Error 127
```

I have double-checked all my environment variables, PATH, and CYGWIN_HOME, etc., still doesn't work. 
Any advice from someone who's been through the same issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a make error. Are you sure all required libraries are installed in your Cygwin environment?

Comment: Could you post your makefile, or at least the relevant rules in your makefile? Is the Rscript program installed and in the PATH?

Comment: Yes Rscript is installed and its path is present in the PATH environment variable. 

I installed the full devel package of cygwin, it's all I need. Could you be more specific concerning the libraries? thanks

Comment: Could be a locale issue, judging from "commande introuvable". Does it work better with `export LANG=C LC_ALL=C`? Maybe somewhere some part of the build parses messages and gets confused with French.

Comment: No Jens, it doesn't solve it. It's weird I've been a week on this. It just doesn't work.
Perhaps I'd better uninstall everything and reinstall? I'm not sure whether the problem is due to a DLL conflict, because the Rtools install DLLs that CYGWIN also installs. I'm not sure though, I've tried installing Rtools without the DLLs, and with the DLLs, the problem is still there.